# Not able to run Ludwig commands in terminal, and in Python also as it is saying no module installed named Ludwig

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, ludwig

When is run "ludwig --version", it shows me the version of Ludwig installed without any errors, but when I try Ludwig train command it is showing me the error.

The error which I got after running "ludwig train --config rotten_tomatoes.yaml --dataset rotten_tomatoes.csv" is as follows:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/ludwig", line 5, in <module>
    from ludwig.cli import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ludwig/cli.py", line 19, in <module>
    import ludwig.contrib
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ludwig/contrib.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .contribs import contrib_registry
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ludwig/contribs/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .mlflow import MlflowCallback
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ludwig/contribs/mlflow/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ludwig.utils.data_utils import chunk_dict, flatten_dict, save_json, to_json_dict
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ludwig/utils/data_utils.py", line 34, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64)))
```

And when I run "from ludwig.api import LudwigModel", it doesn't work either.

Not able to figure out how to solve the error, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still running into this error with the latest Ludwig release, i.e., Ludwig 0.6.4? We fixed this in Ludwig 0.6 so you shouldn't see this anymore.